# A research department is investigating the duration of a tire.The department wants to show it exceeds a certain value. Formulate the hypothesis

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

> The research department of a tire manufacturer is investigating the
>   duration of a tire using a new rubber component. 16 tires were
>   produced and the duration was tested. The average duration and stdev
>   were 60139.7 and 3645.94, respectively. The department wants to show
>   that the average duration of the new tire exceeds 60000 km. Formulate
>   the appropriate test and hypothesis, using alpha = 0.05

I did

$$H_0 : \mu>60000$$

I am not given the variance of the population, so I use the t-student distribution for the test:

$$T_0 = \frac{x-\mu_o}{s/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{60139.7-60000}{3645.94/4}=0.153266373$$

The upper bound:

$$T_{0.05,15}=2.947 $$

So... what do I conclude? Do I reject the hypothesis? I'm trying to imagine a t-student distribution where the upper bound is 2.947 and the acceptation area is everything above it. T_0 is below it, so is it false?

Answer (score 1):

For the (one-sided) test here, you would only reject the null hypothesis if your calculated test statistic ($0.1532\ldots$) were greater than the critical value ($2.947$). Since this is not the case, you *fail to reject* the null hypothesis.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing this. If you had to draw this how would you draw it?

Comment: Draw a $t_{15}$-distribution density (a bell-shaped type curve). The critical value is somewhere far to the right of the curve (such that the area under the curve to the right of this point is $0.05$ (the $\alpha$)). We reject the null hypothesis in this particular hypothesis test only if our calculated test statistic lies to the right of this critical value (i.e. lies in the upper $5\%$ of the distribution). In this case, the calculated test statistic is clearly *left* of the critical point (doesn't fall into that upper $5\%$ of the distribution), so we *fail to reject* the null hypothesis).

Comment: I think I understand now... I was imagining all those values as "real" values, not as statistics... if that makes sense.